# Same table repeated when trying to display multiple tables on a single HTML page with getJson and Datatables

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables, getjson

I have 3 JSON files. I want to transform them into 3 HTML tables on a single HTML page and from there use DataTables to add functionality like sorting and filtering.

I can achieve this successfully when dealing with 1 JSON file only. However, I cannot achieve this with 3 JSON files. The first JSON file to be mentioned in the code is repeated 3 times.

I am using `getJSON` to transform the JSON to HTML. (This is not a requirement -- it is only because as a new Javascript learner it is the only method I'm comfortable with as of yet.)

The DataTables documentation is clear on the code required to achieve this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table.display').DataTable();
} );
```

Also, many answers on Stack Overflow clarify that a table ID is required to assign a JSON file to its appropriate table:

```
$('#table1').DataTable();
```

I have tried many solutions. I understand they are poor. Among them:

- Putting all code in one script vs. separate scripts (same result)
- Putting each script into a unique HTML file and assembling the output on the main HTML page (`<div id="test1"><script>$("#test1").load("test1.html");</script></div>`) (same result)
- Moving `$('#table1').DataTable();` to different locations in the code, particularly to try to include the `getJSON` inside it (due to my incorrect positioning, IDE always indicates there are errors in code)
- Adding code to destroy a table after it is created (no tables are shown)
- Various configurations of ids and classes

Latest iteration on the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Release Notes</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#table1').DataTable();
            $.getJSON('table1.json', function (json) {
                var tr;
                for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                    tr = $('<tr/>');
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].releaseName + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].software + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].sqlServerVersion + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].releaseDate + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].releaseNote + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].productsAffected + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].id + "</td>");
                    $('table').append(tr);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#table2').DataTable();
            $.getJSON('table2.json', function (json) {
                var tr;
                for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                    tr = $('<tr/>');
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].releaseName + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].software + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].sqlServerVersion + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].releaseDate + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].releaseNote + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].productsAffected + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].id + "</td>");
                    $('table').append(tr);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#table3').DataTable();
            $.getJSON('table3.json', function (json) {
                var tr;
                for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                    tr = $('<tr/>');
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].releaseName + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].software + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].sqlServerVersion + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].releaseDate + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].releaseNote + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].productsAffected + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].id + "</td>");
                    $('table').append(tr);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="table" class="table1">
        <thead>
            <th>Release</th>
            <th>Software</th>
            <th>SQL Server version</th>
            <th>Release date</th>
            <th>Release note</th>
            <th>Products affected</th>
            <th>ID</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table id="table" class="table2">
        <thead>
            <th>Release</th>
            <th>Software</th>
            <th>SQL Server version</th>
            <th>Release date</th>
            <th>Release note</th>
            <th>Products affected</th>
            <th>ID</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table id="table" class="table3">
        <thead>
            <th>Release</th>
            <th>Software</th>
            <th>SQL Server version</th>
            <th>Release date</th>
            <th>Release note</th>
            <th>Products affected</th>
            <th>ID</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Sample JSON:

```
[{
    "releaseDate": "05/22/18",
    "sqlServerVersion": "N/A",
    "software": "SoftwareA",
    "releaseName": "4.3.13.0",
    "releaseNote": "Note1",
    "type": "Bug",
    "productsAffected": "Product1",
    "id": "140804",
    "Type": "Patched bug"
}, 
{
    "releaseDate": "06/05/18",
    "sqlServerVersion": "SQL 2012",
    "software": "SoftwareB",
    "releaseName": "18.1.18156.02",
    "releaseNote": "Note2",
    "type": "Bug",
    "productsAffected": "Product2",
    "id": "141406",
    "Type": "Patched bug"
},
{
    "releaseDate": "06/05/18",
    "sqlServerVersion": "SQL 2016",
    "software": "SoftwareC",
    "releaseName": "4.0.94.06",
    "releaseNote": "Note3",
    "type": "Bug",
    "productsAffected": "Product3",
    "id": "141623",
    "Type": "Patched bug"
}]
```

Thank you for any insight or recommendations.

Comment: Answering from mobile so please forgive any typo. The first problem that I see is the getjson and the for loop over it. If you look at datatables docs you will see its not necessary. You just have to set the json string as source then define the columns in html or in script and you're basically done. https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/

Comment: This helped me - thanks @Enrico

Comment: I'm Glad to hear that. You can now either answer your one question or close it.